# Problems sending ArrayList<MyObject> in intent

Tags: java, android

I've created my first custom BaseAdapter and am attempting to pull data from AWS dynamoDB(This works) and place into an object ArrayList, send threw an intent and then a ListView in the next activity. For some reason the ArrayList gives a null pointer error in activity 2.

Activity 1:

```
//fyi threw a log I can confirm floridaArray is not null   
 mbundle = new Bundle();
                mbundle.putParcelableArrayList("floridaArray", floridaArray);
                intent.putExtra("mBundle", mbundle);
```

Activity 2:

```
// Now the ArrayList is null
 ArrayList<FloridaStatutes> floridaArray = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("floridaArray");
```

Logcat:

```
12-09 14:44:38.279 5316-5316/com.ronaldpitt.floridalaw E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.ronaldpitt.floridalaw, PID: 5316
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ronaldpitt.floridalaw/com.ronaldpitt.floridalaw.views.TitleTwoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.ronaldpitt.floridalaw.views.TitleTwoActivity.onCreate(TitleTwoActivity.java:48)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you implements Parcelable on its object ?

Comment: @victorldavila yes it is

Comment: Much too little code. Please read about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of sending `Intent` is not correct, 
the `Intent` itself has method `putParcelableArrayListExtra`.

to get your code works you should use

```
getIntent().getBundleExtra("mBundle").getParcelableArrayListExtra("floridaArray");
```

or

```
intent.getExtras().getParcelableArrayListExtra("floridaArray");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get the ArrayList in the wrong way.

Instead to put the Bundle object in the extra argument like this:

```
 Bundle mbundle = new Bundle();
 mbundle.putParcelableArrayList("floridaArray", floridaArray); 
 intent.putExtra("mBundle", mbundle);
```

Try to put the Bundle object in the extras argument like this

```
 Bundle mbundle = new Bundle();
 mbundle.putParcelableArrayList("floridaArray", floridaArray); 
 intent.putExtras("mBundle", mbundle);
```

And in the second Activity you will get the ArrayList like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent()
Bundle mBundle = intent.getExtras();
ArrayList<FloridaStatutes>floridaArray = mBundle.getParcelableArrayListExtra("floridaArray");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the data through a Bundle, you also need to get it back from the Bundle.

In your second activity, do -

```
 if (intent != null) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras()
        ArrayList<FloridaStatutes> floridaArray = bundle.getParcelableArrayListExtra("floridaArray");
 }
```